# how to create graphs in jsf?

Tags: jsf, graph

Can anyone give details about creating graphs like bars and lines in jsf ? which one is best ? I want graphs by taking data from database dynamically and should work offline.I want each and every 
step of installation  and execution.please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look for component libraries which offers graph (chart) components.

For example [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) ([demo](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/chartsHome.jsf)) and [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org/) ([demo](http://openfaces.org/components/#Chart)).